# Prove that this linear algebra system with sums has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a linear algebra system $Ax=b$, $A$ an $n\times n$ Matrix with $a_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n{ \left( c^{kn+j} \right)^i }$, I want to prove that a solution exists, modulo a prime $p$ that allows $c$ to have multiplicative order at least $n^2$, and $b_i = e^{2 \pi i/n}$.

**NOTE**

The matrix is very similar to sums of Vandermonde matrices, so that could be a possible approach.

Comment: Certainly there has to be some restrictions on $c$ or $b$.  If $c=1$, $n=2$, and $b=(1,2)$, then there is no solution.

Comment: @Callus:  You're right, there are restrictions on $b$ and $c$, although I originally thought that there didn't need to be.  I've corrected the question.